# Software to draw different prisms

Tags: linux, drawing

I need to draw a number of different regular 3d prisms. For example,

[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

What is the simplest tool to help me do this in Linux? I would like to avoid having to do lots of math if possible.

Comment: What about tikz?

Comment: @Navaro That's a good idea.

Comment: Does [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/71545/a-tool-or-software-to-draw-3d-stacked-blocks) help in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Tikz seems to be a good choice in this case. Take a look at this [gallery exmaples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/).

Comment: I would like to avoid having to work out the coordinates by hand. Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean exactly. But Tikz is scripting language