# A tool or software to draw 3D stacked blocks

Tags: 3d, drawing

I am looking for a relatively easy way to generate the following 3D graphics (In Windows, or Linux):

[image]

I appreciate any recommendations

Comment: Just the blocks or also the text and labels? What format should the result be? Any format, JPG, SVG, 3D?

Comment: If you pose this question on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ they will happily tell you how to do it in LaTeX/Tikz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the graphic is isometric, it seems you don't need a too realistic drawing. In that case, I would use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/). Inkscape it not a 3D tool, it's a 2D tool. But as you'll see you can get a 3D-like result.

Inkscape is gratis and creates vector graphics that have good quality and can be exported to pixel graphics.

1. Create a rectangle and single click it a few times until you see these arrows:

[image: Rectangle with modifiers]

2. Drag the right middle arrow down to make it a trapezoid.

If you want a flat look, best use an angle that is a multiple of 15°. Doing so will simplify later changes which require the same angle. Getting a multiple of 15° can be achieved by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Remember the angle for later changes. An angle of 30° looks just right.

[image: Trapezoid]

3. Duplicate (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>) and flip (<kbd>H</kbd>) it to create the right side of a cube.
4. Enable snapping to edges and move it until it snaps

[image: Snapping to edge]

5. Create a square and rotate by 45°

[image: Rotated square]

Getting the correct angle is best achieved by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, which snaps every 15°.

6. Move the sqare until it snaps to the edge of the cube

[image: Square snapping]

7. Use resizing at *right bottom* corner to snap it on the other side. I find that it is quite important to use the right bottom corner. The right middle item does not snap to corners.

[image: Resizing]

8. Resize at the top middle icon to finalize a cube

[image: Single cube]

9. Set fill color to and adjust line weights as needed
10. Add the text
11. Center vertically and horizontally over a side using these alignment buttons

[image: Centering]

12. Create two duplicates of the text (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>)
13. Move the duplicates to their sides and center them

[image: Cube with labels]

To get a flat look, take these steps (this was edited later, so it will not show up like this in future steps):

a) shear the left text by the same amount of degrees as you did for the rectangle:

[image: Sheared text]

b) shear the right text by the same amount in the opposite direction:

[image: Sheared text 2]

c) the most difficult part is on the top, also because there are two options. Either shear as for the left text and then rotate counter-clockwise. Or shear as for the right text and then rotate clockwise. The rotation angle is 90 minus the angle used for shearing in step 2. The effect is best observed with a number that has a flat bottom. Thus I chose the number 2. The bottom of the text should clearly aligh with the edge of the cube.

[image: Sheared and rotated text]

14. Mark all 6 items (3 sides and 3 text) and group them (<kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>) to keep the arrangement.
15. Duplicate the cube (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>) and move the duplicate to the next position, snapping at edges. Go from bottom to top first. In the particular example, build 4 cubes.

[image: A pillar of 4 cubes]

16. Duplicate the whole pillar and move each copy from back to front right

[image: Wall of cubes]

17. Duplicate the whole wall and move each copy from back to front left

[image: Cube of cubes]

18. Change the texts
19. Add axes and labels

[image: Final result]

The process seems slow in the beginning, but as you can see, it's quite fast in the end. The whole process took 49 minutes, including the creation of screenshots and writing this answer.

For flat axis labels, shear and rotate similarly as for the cube descriptions.

[image: Flat look]

Comment: Actually there seems to be a bug with snapping to corners. Some of the cubes are a few pixels off. :-( I also noticed that Inkscape became a little slow, even with 24 cubes only (that's just 144 objects, not so much).

Comment: It's amazing! Thank you very much for the detailed steps.

Comment: Yup! That's what an answer ***should*** be like! An example to us all :-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: thanks for the kind words

Comment: @Navaro: actually it's easier to do it in earlier steps so that the change automatically propagates to all cubes automatically. But anyway, I also did it afterwards, so it's definitely possible. It's quite late here in Germany. I put a reminder for tomorrow to add the information

Comment: @Navaro: I've updated the description. Ideally you have used snapping in step 2. Then see step 13. You'll identify the new images by their different blue color.

Comment: In recent versions of Inkscape, the skew snap modifier is changed to `Alt` key (even for rotation, the `Ctrl` key still works, but will be removed later).